# Making sheets in C# windows forms

Tags: c#, richtextbox, windows-forms-designer

I want to create a simple windows form application which looks like Microsoft Word. I am using `RichTextBox` control right now. I did not find any way to make it have multiple pages, as Microsoft Word does. I just need a control (I guess it is *RichTextbox*) that can have multiple pages. I have tried `RichTextBox` but it was completely useless. Is there any other control or does `Microsoft Word` have any `API` to interact with through C# code? Is there any control to use?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/building-mdi-winforms-application-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: Do you mean *multiple pages in the same RichTextBox*? If so, that's not possible; RichTextBox doesn't support that functionality. MS Word does not use RichTextBox for it's content; it uses a custom interface built specifically for Word.

Comment: @MennanKara actually I need something like Microsoft word. it has pages and sheets that can capture text. I do not need multiple forms to be shown inside another form.

Comment: @KenWhite Is there any way to create such control? or is there any ready-to-use control?

Comment: There is no way to do so with RichTextBox (as I've said previously). There is no standard control that will do so (which is why a custom interface was developed for Word). We can't recommend third-party controls here (that's off-topic according to the [help/on-topic]), and I'm not aware of one anyway.

Comment: Microsoft Word has many faces. A RTB will not display pages, even if you load a rtf document with valid page breaks. You can easily insert page breaks, but they will only show in word or when printing..

Comment: I have rolled back your change. Please do not change your question like you did, especially after you have an accepted answer. If you have anything further to add put it at the end of your existing question or simply just ask a new one.

Comment: What do you want to use this for? Because Word has a form element (at least for WinForms, I can only assume it's the same for WPF) specifically intended to view Word documents in. If this is done for viewing purposes and not heavy editing, you might be better off using the existing  Word plugin.

Comment: @Media - Please do what you need to to get back your ability to ask new questions, but don't do substantive changes to your existing questions. This question is about WinForms - please don't change it to be about WPF.

Comment: @Media - I do understand why you changed it, but it's not the right thing to do here on this site. The question and answers are here for the community first, and the asker second. You need to ask a new question if you have new requirements and let the historical questions stay as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [closest solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192495(v=office.11).aspx) that I can suggest, but it is not exactly what you are asking for. 
Basically, you can use some of the Microsoft office objects and classes, but it is not just a plug and play interface and requires some work on your end.
You may like [this one](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Word_Example01) too (again not a simple rich text control)